# How to access hdfs by URI consisting of H/A namenodes in Spark which is outer hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

Now I have some Spark applications which store output to HDFS.

Since our hadoop cluster is consisting of namenode H/A, and spark cluster is outside of hadoop cluster (I know it is something bad) I need to specify HDFS URI to application so that it can access HDFS.

But it doesn't recognize name service so I can only give one of namenode's URI, and if it fails, modify configuration file and try again.

Accessing Zookeeper for revealing active seems to very annoying, so I'd like to avoid.

Could you suggest any alternatives?

Comment: you can use Active NameNode URI to connect. It should be like this : hdfs://hostname:8020

Comment: Sorry but I already did it. I want to know how to find active namenode without manual revealing.

Comment: http://<namenode_hostname>:50070/dfshealth.jsp. here you will get which is on active state.

Comment: You can use this command too `hadoop dfsadmin -report` to get the status.

Comment: Thanks for additional information, but I'm trying to avoid "manual" revealing. Spark Application should find active namenode automatically.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose your nameservice is 'hadooptest', then set the hadoop configurations like below.
You can get these information from hdfs-site.xml file of remote HA enabled HDFS.

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("dfs.nameservices", "hadooptest")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.hadooptest", "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("dfs.ha.namenodes.hadooptest", "nn1,nn2")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("dfs.namenode.rpc-address.hadooptest.nn1", "10.10.14.81:8020")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("dfs.namenode.rpc-address.hadooptest.nn2", "10.10.14.82:8020")
```

After this, you can use the URL with 'hadooptest' like below.

```
test.write.orc("hdfs://hadooptest/tmp/test/r1")
```

check [here](https://mungeol-heo.blogspot.com/2016/12/accessing-remote-ha-enabled-hdfs.html) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make a H/A HDFS cluster as your default config (mostly the case) that applies to every application started through `spark-submit` or `spark-shell`. you could write the cluster information into `spark-defaults.conf`.

```
sudo vim $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf
```

And add the following lines. assuming your HDFS cluster name is `hdfs-k8s`

```
spark.hadoop.dfs.nameservices   hdfs-k8s
spark.hadoop.dfs.ha.namenodes.hdfs-k8s  nn0,nn1
spark.hadoop.dfs.namenode.rpc-address.hdfs-k8s.nn0 192.168.23.55:8020
spark.hadoop.dfs.namenode.rpc-address.hdfs-k8s.nn1 192.168.23.56:8020
spark.hadoop.dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.hdfs-k8s    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider
```

It should work when your next application launched.

```
sc.addPyFile('hdfs://hdfs-k8s/user/root/env.zip')
```

Answer (score 1):

For kerberos enabled clusters, you can access HDFS using following properties. More information [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithNFS.html). These information you can get from remove HA `hdfs-site.xml` file.

```scala
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("dfs.nameservices", "testnameservice")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.testnameservice", "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("dfs.ha.namenodes.testnameservice", "nn1,nn2")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("dfs.namenode.rpc-address.testnameservice.nn1", "namenode1_hostname:8020")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("dfs.namenode.rpc-address.testnameservice.nn2", "namenode2_hostname:8020")
spark.read.csv("hdfs://testnameservice/path/to/hdfs/sample.csv")
```

If you have also set spark to access kerberos token while launching with this property `spark.kerberos.access.hadoopFileSystems` for [spark > 3.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html#kerberos) or `spark.kerberos.access.namenodes` for Spark < 3.0 as mentioned [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/running-on-yarn.html#spark-properties). Unfortunately, for this, it requires only active namenode configuration and you have to poll namenode service or namenode at `http://namenode_service:50070/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus` and retrieve active namenode.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy hadoop configuration dir to your spark cluster
2. Point spark to this dir by setting HADOOP_CONF_DIR in spark-env.sh

e.g.

```
echo "HADOOP_CONF_DIR=\"/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop\"" > spark-env.sh
```

Comment: It should be 2 >> so it doesn't overwrite the whole file

Answer (score 0):

I came across the similar type of issue. In my case, i was having the list of hosts of HA enabled environment, but no information above the "Active" node.

To solve the problem, i used the **webhdfs** call to get the status of each node, this is the webhdfs call that i used in my code -

***curl 'http://[hdfsHost]:50070/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus'***

I make above call with different HDFS hosts. It return "state" of each node in json output, like this

```
 { 
  "..." : [ {
    "name" : "Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus",
     "modelerType" : "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode",
     "State" : "active",
    .......
  } ]
}
```

if node is stand by you will get **"State" : "standby"**

Once you get the JSON, you can parse the json and get the **state** value.