# Automatically connect to HDFS secondary NN from Java application, once the primary NN goes down

Tags: java, hadoop, configuration, hdfs, namenode

I have a simple java client that saves files to HDFS - configured with 1 name node. For this, I use a hadoop configuration, specifing the default filesystem like:

```
org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://NNip:port");
```

However, in the future, I will need to connect to a hdfs configured with 1 active namenode and 1 standby namenode and in case the active namenode goes down, automatically use the standby namenode.

Does anyone have any advice on how this could be achieved? Any link / example would be much appreciated, as I am still new to anything related to the Hadoop platform.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Configuration`  variable will by default read an hdfs-site.xml file in your classpath.

Ideally, you should have this file with your Java application, or otherwise define a `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` environment variable in the OS. This is how the `hdfs` CLI tools are work, for example, which just forward to Java classes.

Then, if your cluster is using Namenode HA, it should already know what the value of `fs.defaultFS` is set to, so you don't need to set that yourself.

If you wanted to do it programmatically, you need to configure Zookeeper for the namenodes and a ["nameservice" for HDFS, which properties can be found in that XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39445389/2308683)